# Getting this error: This solver needs samples of at least 2 classes in the data, but the data contains only one class: '2'

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, logistic-regression

I have a code that is supposed to do these things:

- Load already trained model
- Load an unseen dataset
- Create a pipeline which takes Bert encoder  (SentenceTransformer('all-mpnet-base-v2')) and my trained model.
- Then randomly choose a row from dataset, encode it, and predict it
- Then ask if the prediction is correct. If not, then ask for the  correct prediction and retrain the model with the right prediction

I have this following code:

```
random_row = full_df.sample(1)
X = random_row[['mmgid', 'body','preprocessedBody']]  # select specific columns
article = np.random.choice(X['preprocessedBody'])
encoded_text = bert_model.encode([article])

prediction = multi_model.predict(encoded_text)[0]
print(X['body'])
print(f"Prediction: {prediction}")


# Ask the user if the prediction is correct
response = input("Is this prediction correct? (yes/no)")
# If the prediction is incorrect, ask the user for the correct classification
if response.lower() == 'no':
    correct_classification = input("What is the correct classification for this article?")
    

    
    # Retrain the model using the original article and the correct classification
    multi_model.fit([encoded_text2], [correct_classification])


    # Test the updated model by classifying the same article again
    updated_prediction = multi_model.predict([article])

    # Display the new prediction to the user
    print(f"The updated model predicts that this article belongs to the '{updated_prediction}' category.")
```

But I am getting this error:

```
-> 1183     raise ValueError(
   1184         "This solver needs samples of at least 2 classes"
   1185         " in the data, but the data contains only one"
   1186         " class: %r"
   1187         % classes_[0]
   1188     )
   1190 if len(self.classes_) == 2:
   1191     n_classes = 1

ValueError: This solver needs samples of at least 2 classes in the data, but the data contains only one class: '2'
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: What do you understand from the error message? It clearly says you need samples of at least two classes, and you have only one.

Comment: Is this error coming during prediction or during retraining ?

Comment: It is coming during retraining

Comment: What are you using to do the training and retraining? This looks like a scikit-learn question, and logistic regression is a tag. But incremental training with `partial_fit` takes a few extra steps.